# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at localhost:49167

Tags: docker, testcontainers

I am using test containers library to launch a container. It worked for a while but currently running into this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at localhost:49167

    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:201)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:205)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
```

I looked at the resource reaper code and it seems like it is failing here

```
public synchronized void performCleanup() {
    this.registeredContainers.forEach(this::stopContainer);
    this.registeredNetworks.forEach(this::removeNetwork); //FAILS HERE
    this.registeredImages.forEach(this::removeImage);
}
```

Comment: which Testcontainers version are you using and can you please add the code for your failing test?

Comment: @rieckpil 1.15.2 and Ubuntu 20.02

Comment: When I restarted docker the problem went away but that is me shooting blind. May I know what is causing this issue? Because this problem persisted for a while

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the issue again it's quite hard to say what issue caused this. What's your Docker version?

Comment: Docker version is 20.10.5

Comment: @user1870400 were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 17):

**Possible Windows solution:**

I tried everything mentioned here but nothing worked.

If anyone is still facing the issue they can give this one a try... this worked for me.

This works for windows:

1. open you PowerShell in administrator mode.
2. run `net stop winnat`
3. run `net start winnat`

Doing this resolved this issue on my setup. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

I can confirm that this is resolved by updating testcontainers to 1.16.0 version

Was facing the same exception with testcontainers 1.15.3

Windows 10, Docker desktop 4.0.0

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue. Same Docker-for-Mac version.

Solution for me was to disable "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" in Preferences: [image: Preferences]

Answer (score 10):

For me, restarting the local docker engine solved the problem.

On Linux with SystemD, it's done this way:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: indeed: "sudo service docker restart" solved the problem.

Comment: Same for Rancher Desktop

Comment: I am using colima and stopping starting colima did the trick:
`colima stop`
`colima start`

Answer (score 1):

I'm am a Windows 11 machine, and had the same issue.

It turned out that a vast number of ports were allocated by the service "IP helper" (relates to ipv6 support), i.e. ports prior allocated by TestContainers, or other services. They were allocated for weeks by *IP helper* but never, or rarely, released. After permanently disabling service *IP helper*, all issues were resolved, and the set-up works great since then, without any observed side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Setting: Windows11 + Rancher Desktop

Restarting Rancher Desktop did not help. However, restarting my computer did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Setting: Windows11 + Rancher Desktop

For me was helpful this comment: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3609#issuecomment-769615098

In file testcontainer.properties at your user folder add:

`ryuk.container.privileged=false`

Set environment variable for your user:

`TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true`